# Дублирующиеся записи в ТЗ

Tags: 1с

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать внешний отчет. Не совсем получается то, что бы хотелось. При просмотре таблицы значений видно, что некоторые записи дублируются, иногда и "тройнируются" =) Уже при печати отчета список выводит правильный, но общее количество и сумму выводит по дублирующимся записям. Скажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

1С УПП 1.3.25.1
Запрос -

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
Реализация.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
Реализация.Количество КАК Количество,
Реализация.Цена КАК Цена,
Реализация.Сумма КАК Сумма,
Реализация.Контрагент КАК Контрагент,
Ном.Спецификация КАК Спецификация
ИЗ
(ВЫБРАТЬ
    РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    СУММА(РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Количество) КАК Количество,
    СУММА(РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Цена) КАК Цена,
    СУММА(РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Сумма) КАК Сумма,
    РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Ссылка.Контрагент КАК Контрагент
ИЗ
    Документ.РеализацияТоваровУслуг.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары
ГДЕ
    РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Ссылка.Проведен
    И РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Ссылка.Дата МЕЖДУ &ПериодС И &ПериодПо

СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО
    РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Номенклатура,
    РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Ссылка.Контрагент) КАК Реализация
    ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ (ВЫБРАТЬ
        СпрНоменклатура.Ссылка КАК Номенклатура,
        СпецификацииНоменклатурыВыходныеИзделия.Ссылка КАК Спецификация
    ИЗ
        Справочник.Номенклатура КАК СпрНоменклатура
            ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Справочник.СпецификацииНоменклатуры.ВыходныеИзделия КАК СпецификацииНоменклатурыВыходныеИзделия
            ПО СпрНоменклатура.Ссылка = СпецификацииНоменклатурыВыходныеИзделия.Номенклатура
    ГДЕ
        НЕ СпрНоменклатура.ЭтоГруппа) КАК Ном
    ПО Реализация.Номенклатура = Ном.Номенклатура
ИТОГИ
СУММА(Количество),
СУММА(Цена),
СУММА(Сумма)
ПО
ОБЩИЕ,
Номенклатура
```

Не хватает баллов чтобы скрины выложить (
Здесь 2 файла - xml - распечатанная таблица, то, что выводит, второй - скрин - таблица значений с дублирующимися записями.

http://files.mail.ru/4290T7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сразу вопрос. почему вы собираете данные по документам, а не по регистру. Не помню что там в УПП, что-то типа Продажи...
2. Зачем делаете два подзапроса - по реализациям и по справочнику. Можно же сразу спецификацию привязать к номенклатуре из документа.
3. Если у вас возможна ситуация когда одна номенклатура входит в спецификацию по нескольким изделиям, то будет задвоение, затроение...

Comment: Я новичок в этом не легком деле, поэтому возможны такие косяки..а как привязать спецификацию к номенклатуре?

Comment: ну точно также. 

    ИЗ
    Документ.РеализацияТоваровУслуг.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары
    ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Справочник.СпецификацииНоменклатуры.ВыходныеИзделия как ВыходныеИзделия ПО РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Номенклатура = ВыходныеИзделия.Номенклатура

В общем надо упрощать запрос, смотреть откуда дубли лезут.

Answer (score 0):

1. Не используйте вложенных запросов - это привилегия только для 8.1.
2. Для получения данных используются РЕГИСТРЫ, а документы - ТОЛЬКО для ввода данных в регистры. (важно, т.к. документы есть еще и непроведенные, и помеченные на удаление).
3. Используйте СКД (схема компоновки данных). Все типовые отчеты уже написаны на СКД, посмотрите любой.

Comment: Да, но для чего-то же 1С оставили пункт вложенные запросы..,а в запросе у меня идет проверка на проведенные..
СКД я еще не умею пользоваться, пробовал, но ничего не получилось, а время ограниченно ((

Comment: Это право не означает, что мой ответ был не верен, как считаете ?
Если у Вас есть ТЗ  и сама внешняя обработка, думаю, я смогу помочь. Надумаете - пишите leobelissimo@mail.ru (личный)

Answer (score 0):

Решил это так -

```
ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
СпецификацииНоменклатурыВыходныеИзделия.Ссылка.Наименование КАК Спецификация,
Продажи.Номенклатура,
Продажи.Количество КАК Количество,
РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Цена КАК Цена,
Продажи.Стоимость КАК Сумма,
Продажи.Контрагент
ИЗ
РегистрНакопления.Продажи КАК Продажи
    ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Справочник.СпецификацииНоменклатуры.ВыходныеИзделия КАК СпецификацииНоменклатурыВыходныеИзделия
    ПО Продажи.Номенклатура = СпецификацииНоменклатурыВыходныеИзделия.Номенклатура
    ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Документ.РеализацияТоваровУслуг.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары
    ПО Продажи.Номенклатура = РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Номенклатура
ГДЕ
Продажи.Период МЕЖДУ НАЧАЛОПЕРИОДА(&ПериодС, ДЕНЬ) И КОНЕЦПЕРИОДА(&ПериодПо, ДЕНЬ)
И Продажи.МоментВремени = РеализацияТоваровУслугТовары.Ссылка.МоментВремени
ИТОГИ
СУММА(Количество),
СУММА(Цена),
СУММА(Сумма)
ПО
ОБЩИЕ,
Спецификация
```

Comment: Цену лучше считать делением стоимости на количество, тогда соединение с реализацией будет не нужно. Кроме того, к самой таблице регистра обращаются в редких случаях, обычно пользуются виртуальной таблицей в данном случае Обороты.

    ИЗ 
    РегистрНакопления.Продажи.Обороты(&ПериодС, &ПериодПо, Период, ) как Продажи

Comment: Если нужно собирать движения только по реализациям (в продажи пишут движения несколько документов), то можно просто добавить фильтр на тип регистратора.

    ИЗ 
    РегистрНакопления.Продажи.Обороты(&ПериодС, &ПериодПо, Регистратор, ) как Продажи
    ...
    ГДЕ
      Продажи.Регистратор ССЫЛКА Документ.РеализацияТоваровУслуг

Comment: цену он считает с разрядностью аж в ~6 знаков, а как в запросе ее уменьшить до 2х? )

Comment: Справка: Содержание - Встроенный язык - Работа с запросами - Синтаксис текста запросов - Ключевые слова и функции - Операторы - Прочие операторы - ВЫРАЗИТЬ (глубоко запихали):

    ВЫРАЗИТЬ(Продажи.Стоимость/Продажи.Количество КАК ЧИСЛО(15,2))